# Java - how to Highlight Squares using a Mouse Listener. (using jframe)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, actionlistener

Im creating a program and im stuck at the moment I want the tiles of the droughts board to glow another colour when its highlighted but im not very good with Actionlistners can someone help me out?

I use several class files and here is the code for each.

This is uni work so as I am learning I don't want the code given to me rather a few snippets and helpful advice to go on. the code in the class files is i think uncompilable due to errors because I don't know how to use actionlistners or mouselisteners yet.

To sum up i need an actionlistener for when my mouse hovers over the game board and the tiles change colour.

as I can only post 2 links I will give the 3 shortest class files on here.

*EDIT*: for ease I have got rid of the links.
*EDIT 2*: I am also sorry if this seems like a begginer question and well im asking because Im a beginner.
*EDIT 3* I have edited the Jframe class to accept mouse listener now I need help changing the color of the tiles, how do i get the color to change from this class file?

*EDIT 4* ok i edited the color variable to public i think if thats what you meant, and also I added your code but I dont know which class is my mouselistener and I dont know how to add that color in the way you have laied it out to me.

*EDIT 5* ok i tied to make this SSCCE not sure if i was able to do it or not, is this what you meant? if so would it be possible to help me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Board extends JPanel 
{

private void setupPieces(int numRows)
{
int numPieces = ((numRows * numRows) - (2 * numRows)) / 4;
for (int i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)


{
    DraughtsPiece p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.LIGHT_PIECE_COLOUR);
    lightPieces.add(p);

    p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.DARK_PIECE_COLOUR);
    darkPieces.add(p);




    DraughtsPiece p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.LIGHT_PIECE_COLOUR);
    lightPieces.add(p);

     p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.DARK_PIECE_COLOUR);
     P.addMouseListener(new <Board.class>);
    darkPieces.add(p);

     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m){
      ((DraughtsPiece) m.getSource()).color=<highlight color goes here>;
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m){
      ((DraughtsPiece) m.getSource()).color=<normal color goes here>;
  }
  }

  darkPieces.add(p);
}

}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the thing is I dont know what I need for the program to function and do the bit im asking for....if i could learn like this I would i usually get sample codes from lectures so i can reference (its how I learn) or by watching a lecture code im not very good (atm) with learning from the internet especially when most tutorials I see i have to filter through everything to get 1 snippet and usually it does not work or out of date. and this SSCCE just makes things harder for me to explain whats going on. (for me anyway)

Comment: *"how to Highlight Sqaures using a Mouse Listener"*  Would take around 20-30 lines of code rather than that 'wall of text' posted above.  Voting to close.

Comment: Ok ive redone the code to SSCCE i hope could you check to see if i have condensed it enough?

Comment: Does that compile in the SSCCE Text Based Compiler?  I'd guess not.  It also contains no `main(String[])`

Comment: is there no way you could give me an example? this is all new to me and this compiler wont let me copy my code into it. http://pscode.org/twc/ i mean an example of SSCCE not my code. On a side note why do you need my main method? im using jframe in another class for my tutorial im not allowed to edit main class and its already correct.

Comment: You have the essence of a question here, but might I recommend a few things? Work on your writing: you don't need to apologize for being a beginner; toss out those sentences. You do need good grammar, spelling and most importantly, succinct thoughts. These things will let us understand you much faster and enable us to help you.

Comment: Why did you remove all your classes? It was useful to see all of them. Please add them back.

Comment: Also, you should replace <highlight color goes here> with the actual color, such as Color.cyan or Color.yellow or new Color(50, 30, 100) or something like that. And why didn't you use an inline class like in my example? It is much easier that way.

Comment: I have fixed it Now and it all works, I used Zove games answer and eventually got it working from just tinkering. I will try and work on how i explain things as well for next time. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hovering you do not want an ActionListener. ActionListeners are only for clicks on JButton, JMenuItem, etc. If you implement MouseListener then the `mouseEntered(MouseEvent)` and the `mouseExited(MouseEvent)` methods will get called whenever the mouse enters or exits one of your pieces.

EDIT: In response to your comments, you can try using this code in your DraughtsBoard.setupPieces method:

EDIT 2: I think you will need a repaint after mouse hovering, but I'm not sure because you removed a lot of your code. I have added code to make the board repaint after a piece color changes.

```
      DraughtsPiece p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.LIGHT_PIECE_COLOUR);
      lightPieces.add(p);

      p = new DraughtsPiece(DraughtsPiece.DARK_PIECE_COLOUR);
      p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
          public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m){
              ((DraughtsPiece) m.getSource()).color=<highlight color goes here>;
              DraughtsBoard.this.repaint(); // see my note
          }
          public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m){
              ((DraughtsPiece) m.getSource()).color=<normal color goes here>;
              DraughtsBoard.this.repaint();
          }
      });
      darkPieces.add(p);
```

And make DraughtsPiece.color public.

NOTE: You can only use DraughtsBoard.this in an inline class like this one. If you decide not to be lazy and actually have DraughtsPiece implement MouseListener, then you will need some other way to access DraughtsBoard such as a public static variable holding the instance of it

MouseAdapter is an extension of MouseListener which makes all extending classes not have to implement all of the methods from MouseListener. This means I can implement just mouseEntered and mouseExited and leave out the other methods from MouseListener which I don't need.

Comment: Thank you though I just found out that im only allowed to do all this for the dark colored sqaures not sure if this changes much? but thanks im trying to implement what you said at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your above comment. If in doubt about anything Java related, always check Oracle's Java tutorials. This might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: ok thanks, just to clarify the drought board has 2 sets of tiles light and dark for the tutorial i must make only the dark colored tiles change color when the mouse is over them. this is the assigment specficiation "You are required to modify the
draughts application so that the dark
squares on the board change colour as the mouse cursor passes over them"

Comment: Then you can only add MouseListeners to the dark colored tiles and not the light colored ones. (To clarify: you have to add a MouseListener to every JComponent that you want to respond to mouse entering and exiting.)

Comment: i tried adding the code too my setup pieces method and im not sure which is my mouselistener class? edit one sec trying that new code you put up.

Comment: Hi ughh im sorry actionlisteners are really one of the things i cannot understand, is it possible you could edit my code to work? I learn better through demonstration and I learn around it if you could get my code to work I will then add in the lines of code that are new while learning what they do at the same time and where they are supposed to go, I know it is allot to ask but im clutching at strings here if you cannot ill end the question here and accept yours as the answer and thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Hello is it possible im not begging for it just asking if you carnt that's fine i just need some confirmation here :)?